# Torch7 user-defined package not found

Tags: torch

I am inside a directory structure where I have:

```
--train.lua
--utils
  --sample.lua
```

train.lua has got an import line saying require('sample'), however when running the code Torch7 complains with the message

```
"module 'sample' not found:No LuaRocks module found for sample
```

I have tried changing instead to require('utils.sample'), but it still crashes. How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the problem you described. Could you post the code in the files?

My three files:

main.lua

```
require 'utils.sample'
help()
```

utils/sample.lua

```
function help()
    print("help")
end
```

I using `th main.lua` to run the code